# R : model.matrix for cv.glmnet drops rows from the dataframe

Tags: r, regression, glmnet, lasso-regression, model.matrix

I am having an issue with creating a matrix of explanatory variables for running ridge and lasso regression using cv.glmnet.

My original data frame is of dimension 1460*81 and consist of several numeric and factor variables. In order to run glmnet, I am attempting to create a matrix of predictors using [model.matrix](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.3.2/topics/model.matrix).

However, when creating model.matrix on my original dataset, some of the rows are being dropped and my response variable and predictors are not of the same length.

Here's the code:

```
str(train1)
'data.frame':   1460 obs. of  80 variables:
$ MSSubClass   : int  60 20 60 70 60 50 20 60 50 190 ...
$ MSZoning     : Factor w/ 5 levels "C (all)","FV",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 4 ...
$ LotFrontage  : num  65 80 68 60 84 85 75 69 51 50 ...
$ LotArea      : int  8450 9600 11250 9550 14260 14115 10084 10382 6120 7420 
$ Street       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Grvl","Pave": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Alley        : Factor w/ 3 levels "Grvl","None",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ LotShape     : Factor w/ 4 levels "IR1","IR2","IR3",..: 4 4 1 1 1 1 4 1 4 4 
$ LandContour  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Bnk","HLS","Low",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
$ Utilities    : Factor w/ 2 levels "AllPub","NoSeWa": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

And now I am passing the data frame to model.matrix to create a matrix.

```
x = model.matrix(SalePrice ~., data = train1)
dim(x)

dim(x)
[1] 1370  260
```

Notice, how n = 1460 * 80 is transformed to 1370 * 260. This is causing a mismatch between lengths of my predictor variables and response variable when I try to run ridge regression.

```
cv.ridge <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0)

Error in glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0) : 
number of observations in y (1460) not equal to the number of rows of x (1370)
```

Any ideas on where to look to ensure the length of the matrix (x) is equal (y)?

Comment: perhaps you have missing data??

Comment: Yes. had to replace a handful of missing values. The lengths are equal now. Thanks!